# Installing python packages on anaconda on macos

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, pyldavis

This may be a silly simple question, but I couldn't find an answer in the documentation of Anaconda or elsewhere. I am a bit of a noob when it comes to Python and I am trying to install a package. The problem is generalizable to other packages.

*specs*

I am working on a macOS Catalina (10.15.5) and using Anaconda as my python environment (python2.7).

*problem*

I am attempting to install the package [pyLDAvis](https://pypi.org/project/pyLDAvis/) in my python environment, but the package isn't available on Anaconda's environment manager, and `pip` or `conda` install isn't working on the Spyder shell. Do `pip` and `conda` installs only work on the Anaconda Prompt? The problem is that I have read that the Anaconda Prompt *only* exists on Windows, and I am on mac. How could I install packages (`pip`, `conda`, or else) on Anaconda?

Am I missing something?

Any help or pointers to documentation would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `conda` already installed and your shell is properly configured, you can activate the `base` environment via

```
conda activate
```

You can also create a new environment, see [manage-environments docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

For more information than given below, see [manage-pkgs docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html).

In case of `conda`, after your environment is activated, you can then install a package via `conda install <package name>`, e.g. the package `numpy`

```
conda install numpy
```

In case of `pip`, after your environment is activated, you can then install a package via `pip install <package name>`, e.g. the package `numpy`

```
pip install numpy
```

I only do this if the package is not available via a conda channel.

If the package is also not available via `pip`, you can download the source and set the package up your self. Usually the package author describes how to set up his/her package.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stefan for the suggestion! I struggled a bit because although `conda` was "already installed", my shell was indeed not "properly configured." I am writing here my solution because it may be a recurring theme for macOS users and had an easy fix.

[Starting with macOS Catalina, macOS uses zsh *and not* bash as the default shell,](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050) and so calling `conda` on zsh had no effect. The error message was: `-zsh: conda: command not found`. I solved this by [changing the default shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/) to bash by running the following command: `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Now that the shell and `conda` are properly configured, I  managed to use `conda activate` as you suggested Stefan.

Finally, the package pyLDAvis could not be installed by `conda install pyldavis` but was installed with `pip install pyldavis`.

Solved!